# snowsql command failing from root user / crontab

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am not able to run **snowsql** script from **crontab**. Its saying **snowsql** command not found.
Please help me to resolve the issue.

Comment: Does snowsql work for *any* user or are you only having problems with the root user? Can you show what your crontab file looks like (the schedule config)

Comment: I tried to provide the path of the crontab file and it is now recognizing the command, but failing due to different error.
Crontab config :
SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/snowflake/snowsql:/home/ssg.petsmart.com/nrahman/python3.8.5/bin:/snowflake/snowsql:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/opt/puppetlabs/bin:/home/ssg.petsmart.com/nrahman/.local/bin:/home/ssg.petsmart.com/nrahman/bin

32 19 * * * /snowsql_scripts/result_tasks_CUSTOMER_PRD.sh > /snowsql_scripts/log.txt 2>&1
#*/30 * * * * /home/ssg.petsmart.com/nrahman/result_tasks_MASTERDATA_PRD.sh

Comment: Error is :
Failed to get the response. Hanging? method: post, url: https://petsmart.okta.com/api/v1/sessions?additionalFields=cookieToken

Answer (score 0):

After including environment variables in crontab , I was able to resolve the issue. The above issue was also related to certificate verification which was resolved after including the certificate path.